# Get Xpath from angleSharp element

Tags: javascript, c#, xpath, anglesharp

Is there any definite way to retrieve the **xPath** of a angleSharp **IElement**

I'm trying to pass an IElement to a javaScript function, so I need a way to convert the angleSharp element to a javaScript Dom element

```
function selectLevels(element, name, level){
    document.querySelectorAll("*").forEach(e => {
        if(e.isEqualNode(element)){
            e.setAttribute('level', level); 
            e.setAttribute('title', name);
        }
    })
}
```

I want to call this javaScript function which is in the page by passing an element from the C# code bellow, but I get an angleSharp not found error from the page.

```
IElement element = mainDoc.QuerySelector("strong");
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "SelectLevel", "selectLevels('" + element + "', '" + name + "', '" + level + "')", true);
```

Comment: `JsValue.FromObject` might help.

Comment: Can you show us your Javascript and C# code you have and which function you want to call?

Comment: In which context do you use `Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript`? Is that in any way related to AngleSharp? Or do you have two DOMs, one of AngleSharp, the other in a browser?

Comment: @MartinHonnen No I've used the `Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript` to call the function in the page from the C# code. no there are no two pages I'm loading the page dynamically to the my asp.Net programme and trying to call that js function using an angleSharp element.

Comment: Perhaps explain in more detail what you are doing. That `Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartUpScript` is I think part of server side ASP.NET to send HTML with Javascript to a browser or client? Are you consuming the ASP.NET page with AngleSharp instead of a browser? Or are you using AngleSharp inside of your server-side ASP.NET code?

Comment: By the way: I don't understand the need of `document.querySelectorAll("*").forEach` in that function, wouldn't `function setLevels(element, name, level) { element.setAttribute('level', level); element.setAttribute('title', name); }` suffice?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a HTML document with JavaScript code and want to call a (global) function in the JavaScript code from C# then the following example works for me with AngleSharp 0.15 and AngleSharp.Js 0.14:

```
        static async Task Main()
        {
            var html = @"<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <script>
    function selectLevels(element, name, level){
      element.dataset.level = level;
      element.dataset.title = name;
    }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Test</h1>
    <section data-level=1 data-title='section 1'>
      <h2>Section test</h2>
    </section>
  </body>
</html>";

            var jsService = new JsScriptingService();

            var config = Configuration.Default.With(jsService);

            var context = BrowsingContext.New(config);

            var document = await context.OpenAsync(req => req.Content(html));

            var selectLevels = jsService.GetOrCreateJint(document).GetValue("selectLevels");

            var jsElement = JsValue.FromObject(jsService.GetOrCreateJint(document), document.QuerySelector("section"));

            selectLevels.Invoke(jsElement, "2", "section 2");

            Console.WriteLine(document.DocumentElement.OuterHtml);
        }
```

So basically you get the function with e.g. `jsService.GetOrCreateJint(document).GetValue("selectLevels");` and call it with its `Invoke` method, passing in string arguments for the simple types and the `IElement` converted with `JsValue.FromObject` e.g. `JsValue.FromObject(jsService.GetOrCreateJint(document), document.QuerySelector("section"))`.

Comment: When I use it like this `var jsElement = JsValue.FromObject(jsService.GetOrCreateJint(document), document.QuerySelector("DIV:nth-of-type(3)>P>STRONG"))` and pass it to the javaScript function, I'm still getting it as a AngleSharp element

Comment: As I said, in the context of script execution by AngleSharp.Js, as in my sample, it should work. Your comments suggest you are using a quite different context or a combination of contexts, without giving any details at all. So perhaps edit your question or ask a new one with minimal but complete samples to demonstrate the issue.